# Using the data of the index column I just added

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I was just reading about PDO::lastInsertId from the PHP documentation, but after some tests I reallized I absolutelly suck at PHP xD and I should investigate more about classes and static methods and more to even understand where to put that code.

Anyway, I'm not actually trying to know the last Inserted Id, I want to get the Index value of the last inserted row of MySQL table. My Index column is called "id" and is set to auto increment everytime I add a new row, yet, when I delete a row the number doesn't update, so the value in the row called "id" may not allways be the same as the row number.

Here is the code that inserts a new row.

```
<?php 

    require('conexion.php');

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $localidad=$_POST['localidad'];
    $saldo=$_POST['saldo'];
    $slastupdate=$_POST['slastupdate'];


    $query="INSERT INTO usuarios (name, email, pass, localidad, saldo, slastupdate) VALUES ('$name','$email','$pass','$localidad','$saldo','$slastupdate')";

    $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);
?>
```

**Update:** For now on, I'm using another query to get the last inserted's row Id... In my case using PDO is not necessary since I'm developing a private app, and there's no risk of mysql injections

```
require_once "../php/new_mysql.php";
$query="INSERT INTO clientes (gira, localidad, nombre, email, proxivisi, saldo) VALUES ('$gira', '$localidad', '$nombre', '$email', '$proxivisi', '$saldo')";
    $agregar=$mysql->query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $querygetid=$mysql->query("SELECT id, proxivisi FROM clientes WHERE nombre='$nombre' AND email='$email'");
    $getid=$querygetid->fetch_assoc();
    $id=$getid['id'];
```

Comment: What do you mean by index value?  What good would a value other than the primary key / auto increment value be?  If you're trying to get the number of rows, that would require a `SELECT count(*)`

Comment: There is no "row number" - you probably mean you want to get count of rows where id less than recently inserted - something like `SELECT count(1) from usuarios WHERE id < [last Inserted Id after your insert]` .

Comment: Actually, I do want to get the primary key / auto increment value. I'm just not sure if I will get that value by the method `PDO::lastInsertId`, and if I could get it by that method, I don't know how to do it. Anyway now that I know there's a way to count the number of rows, I'm guessing I was in the right direction with `PD::lastInsertId`, I should start learning more about PHP classes to know how to apply this to my script :)

Answer (score 1):

@FranCano use @user to notify us of your reply.

Your first problem is you seem to be using mysqli, not PDO in the above code.  mysqli and PDO are different APIs to run MySQL queries and don't share functions. PDO::lastInsertId will give you the auto increment value of the last inserted row.

Start with [PDO::__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) to see how to start a PDO instance and connect to a database. Check [PDO::query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) and the examples listed to see how PDO works.  However, `PDO::query()` is basic and does not protect you from SQL injections.  For your above query you should be used prepared statements since you use user input (POST).  Prepared statements are started with [PDO::prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).  MySQLi has prepared statements too but they are slightly different.

PDO is object oriented, you can't just call `PDO::query()` and `PDO::lastInsertId()`. You create a `PDO` instance to connect to the database, then you create a `PDOStatement` object by using prepare(), then you execute (`PDOStatement::execute`) that `PDOStatement` object to run the query.  Then you can resort to the `lastInsertId()` on the original `PDO` object.

If you don't know OOP or object oriented programming then this will all sound pretty confusing so that is where you need to start your reading.

A quick example is:

```
$pdo = new PDO(..mysql connection information..);
// Create a PDOStatement object
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT into test ('field1', 'field2') VALUES (?, ?)");
// Execute the prepared statement safely inserting the post variables into the ?'s.  This protects against SQL injection attacks.
if ($stmt->execute(array($_POST['value1'], $_POST['value2']))) {
  $id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

Comment: That was a lot of help, I understanded why I couldn't make that code to work.`require_once "../php/new_mysql.php";
$query2="INSERT INTO clientes (gira, localidad, nombre, email, proxivisi, saldo) VALUES ('$gira', '$localidad', '$nombre', '$email', '$proxivisi', '$saldo')";
$agregar=$mysql->query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
$querygetid=$mysql->query("SELECT id, proxivisi FROM clientes WHERE nombre='$nombre' AND email='$email'");
$getid=$querygetid->fetch_assoc();
$id=$getid['id'];
$fecha= date('Y-m-d');
$hora= date('H:i:s');` I solved it by using another query to get the id